# Is there a nice picture of the direct sum of two Möbius bundles?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, mobius-band

This question is not really about mathematics, but I'm looking for a picture about a mathematical statement.

The direct sum of two Möbius bundles is a trivial bundle. Do you know of a nice graphic that shows this? Ie a graphic of $S^1\times [-1,1]^2$ so that the two original Möbius strips are marked in this picture?

Comment: You can superpose two Möbius strip, making them orthogonal to each other, this gives a moving union of two lines which looks like a cross. The direct sum will be the all plane, i.e you get the trivial bundle.

Comment: @N.H. I'm specifically looking for a graphical rendering of this, I want to print it out ;-)

Comment: Do you want the picture to be by computer ? I don't know how to do it. If you don't mind a picture by hand, I can try to do my best but my drawing skills are pretty limited :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm sort of looking for a "canonical" picture if that makes sense, sort of like what [this image](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/AlexandersHornedSphere_1000.gif) does for the horned sphere.

Comment: Best you can have is probably the picture in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009126/global-trivialization-of-m-oplus-m?rq=1