# why non-orientable surface does not separate its normal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I was trying to prove that if $S$ is a non-orientable surface embedded in orientable 3-manifold $M$. Then $S$ does not seperate the normal bundle $NS$ and $M$ as well.

It's easy to check that if $S$ is orientable(for example the cylinder in $\Bbb{R}^3$), $S$ may seperate the normal bundle, I have no idea why the seperating property is related to the orientability of the normal bundle ?

Comment: a surface is non orientable iff it contains a Mobius band, therefore if we move along the middle line the Mobius band you will go from "inside " to the "outside" of $NS \setminus S$ without crossing $S$, however that's not a rigorous proof.

Comment: You know that $NS$ is non-orientable (since $TS$ is non-orientable and $TM|_S$ is orientable), and hence there is a closed loop in $S$ with an orientation-reversing section of $NS$ on it. The claim about $M$ follows from the tubular neighborhood theorem.

Comment: The same link as at [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465483/normal-bundle-of-non-orientable-surface-embedded-in-orientable-3-manifold) may help here, as well.

Comment: hi @Ted Shifting  can you elaborate more on the first claim  why orientation reversing section implies it does not seperate the normal bundle?

Comment: Because you have a path in the complement of the zero section from one element of a fiber to its negative.